# How to avoid IllegalMonitorStateException when using lockInterruptibly on Reentrantlock

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to replace a `syncronized` block with a `ReentrantLock` to support interruption of waiting for the lock. For this, I use the `lockInterruptibly()` method and the idiomatic try/finally block:

```
private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

try
{
  lock.lockInterruptably();
}
catch( InterruptedException e )
{
  Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
}
finally
{
  lock.unlock();
}
```

The problem is that the finally ofcourse also happens when the InterruptedException happens. This results in an `IllegalMonitorStateException`, because the lock is not held by the current thread.

This simple program proves this:

```
public class LockTest
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    System.out.println("START");

    Thread interruptThread = new Thread( new MyRunnable( Thread.currentThread() ) );
    interruptThread.start();
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    Thread takeLockThread = new Thread( new TakeLockRunnable( lock ) );
    takeLockThread.start();

    try
    {
        Thread.sleep( 500 );
        System.out.println("Trying to take lock on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }

    System.out.println( "DONE");
}

private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private Thread m_thread;

    private MyRunnable( Thread thread)
    {
        m_thread = thread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep( 1000 );
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // ignore
        }
        System.out.println( "Interrupting thread " + m_thread.getName() );
        m_thread.interrupt();
    }
}

private static class TakeLockRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private ReentrantLock m_lock;

    public TakeLockRunnable( ReentrantLock lock )
    {
        m_lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Taking lock on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            m_lock.lock();
            Thread.sleep( 20000 );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            m_lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
}
```

It prints this output:

```
START
Taking lock on thread Thread-1
Trying to take lock on thread main
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:877)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1201)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:312)
    at LockTest.main(LockTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:127)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1239)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:431)
    at LockTest.main(LockTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Interrupting thread main
```

Any idea on what the best way is to avoid this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

the `lockInterruptibly()` call should be *outside* the finally block.  note, this is always true when using the `Lock` API (whether you use `lock()` or `lockInterruptibly()`), as you *don't* want to do the "unlock" work unless you have acquired the lock.

```
try {
  lock.lockInterruptibly();
  try {
    // do locked work here
  } finally {
    lock.unlock();
  }
} catch( InterruptedException e ) {
  Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
}
```

Comment: I was first using `isHeldByCurrentThread`, but after reading all the comments, I think this version is the only one that is really correct.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe which comments are you referring to, and why do you think using `isHeldByCurrentThread` is not correct?

Comment: @RobinGreen as it has been over 1 year, I don't exactly remember, but I have the feeling there used to be more/other answers on this question. Anyway, the proper way to do it is given in this answer, so that is all that is important in the end.

Comment: @RobinGreen - there is a deleted answer which attempted to use `isHeldByCurrentThread` to determine if the lock should be released, however it would not work correctly if the lock was held re-entrantly.

Answer (score 2):

Simply using a boolean-flag should take care of this:

```
private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

boolean lockAcquired = false;

try
{
  lock.lockInterruptably();
  lockAcquired = true;
}
catch( InterruptedException e )
{
  Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
}
finally
{
  if(lockAcquired)
  {
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```